# How to work with nested routes in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm new to Ember.js and I stuck with nested routes and I need help.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I think this is called Master-Detail page.

more systematically it looks something like this:

[image]

**UsersIndexRoute** displays list of people.
**UsersShowRoute** displays information for particular person.

Here is my routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users', { path: '/users'}, function() {
    this.route('index', { path: ''}, function() {
      this.route('show', { path: '/:id' });
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

UserIndex Template looks like this:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#link-to 'users.index.show' item.id}} {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

When I try URL like 'http://localhost:4200/users/1' for example, according to debugger I am be able to reach controller 'users.index.show' (the desired one)

[image]

The route for **UserShowRoute** looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({
      outlet: 'detail'
    });
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.id);
  } 
});
```

I am using ember-cli 1.13.8

I hope my explanation makes some sense to you.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can not find the question. You provide code that looks fine. If it does not work, could you post stacktrace

Comment: @kristjanreinhold But, I don't get any error

Comment: @kristjanreinhold when I set ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITION to true, it says 'Transitioned into 'users.index.show'

Comment: @kristjanreinhold I added 'console.log' to the model hook on the UsersShowRoute and it prints to the console. It looks like something wrong template rendering.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold I made repo on github in case I haven't provided enough information https://github.com/SuperManEver/nested_routes

Comment: Git cloned, checking =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i've updated your code abit. mostly the logics of routing itself. Also the each loop was used in a deprecated way.

*router.js*

```
this.resource('users', function() {
  this.route('index');
  this.route('view', { path: 'view/:id' });
});
```

*routes/users/index*

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user');
    } 
});
```

*templates/users/index*

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
   {{#link-to 'users.view' item.id}} 
       {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
   {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

*routes/users/view.js*

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash ({
      person: this.store.find('user', params.id);
    })
  } 
});
```

*templates/users/view.hbs*

```
{{model.person.firstName}}

  ---- content ---
```

Comment: I tried what you gave me and I got `UnrecognizedURLError: /users`  as a result

Comment: @NikitaLuparev On which route was the errro thrown?

Comment: @ I made a mistake, I used old URL, now I've reached view's URL `http://localhost:4200/users/view/2`. Debugger shows that current route is `users.view`, but page is still empty

Comment: @NikitaLuparev . add this line of code to detail view route.... afterModel: function(model, transition) {  }  and add a debugger.

Comment: what is the model returning +

Comment: Are u using ember.rsvp.hash and person.

Comment: this is code for `users.view` route 


`export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {

    
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({

      person: this.store.find('user', params.id)
    });
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    debugger;
  }
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93335/discussion-between-nikita-luparev-and-kristjan-reinhold).